# Laravel 5.2 model save method can set not null fields to empty string automatic?

Tags: laravel-5

My laravel version is 5.2. Today I did a test, in my `posts` table, there are some fields can not be null `name title`. I save a post like this:

```
$post = new App\Post();
$post->name = 'testBook';
$post->save();
```

I found a new record inserted into table, the title field is empty string. So laravel can automatic set not null fields to empty string if I didn't pass values to the attributes?

Comment: No. how can empty string set to not null field, even by laravel?

Comment: If you want your field is null IF it is empty you must insert in your migration  $table->string('title')->nullable()